# How to Make Attribute condition in a report file in Odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo

I have this field in tree view on (test.xml)
#field name="test" optional="hide"
I need in report file side (report.xml), if this field has attribute optional='hide' make this field invisible in the report else print it in the report.
#t out="doc.test"

I expected when i print qweb if i make field in tree view hide it will show on report file print

Comment: How the tree view is related to the qweb report?

Answer (score -1):

You could simply put a `t-if="hide_condition"` in the report template on the node that have the `t-out`